# Go gorm check a model is associated with another model

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a race model

```
type Race struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title   string
    Date    string
    Token   string
    Heats   []Heat   `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    Runners []Runner `gorm:"many2many:race_runners;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
}
```

I want to add runners into heats but before doing so I want to assert that the runner actually is in the race

```
var race models.Race
if err := models.DB.Preload("Runners").Find(&race, "runners.id IN ?", []uint{runner.ID}).Error; err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"error": "Runner not in race!"})
    return
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
near "?": syntax error
```

Because I'm having a many to many relationship between Race and Runners I doubt that I can just do `runners.id` in the condition I pass to my Find method. But I'm not sure how to actually do what I want to achieve. Which is ensure the runner is already in the race before adding it to a heat. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where query wants to be in the `Preload` part. Then you can check the `len(fetchedRace.Runners) < 1`, and if that is true, the runner is not in that race.

```golang
    fetchedRace := Race{}
    db.Preload("Runners", "runners.id = ?", runnerOne.ID).Find(&fetchedRace, race.ID)
```

#### Full working example

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Race struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title   string
    Date    string
    Token   string
    Runners []Runner `gorm:"many2many:race_runners;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
}

type Runner struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("many2many.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    // Migrate the schema
    _ = db.AutoMigrate(&Race{}, &Runner{})

    raceOne := Race{
        Title: "Race One",
    }
    db.Create(&raceOne)

    runnerOne := Runner{
        Name: "Runner One",
    }
    runnerTwo := Runner{
        Name: "Runner Two",
    }

    db.Create(&runnerOne)
    db.Create(&runnerTwo)

    // Associate runners with race
    err = db.Model(&raceOne).Association("Runners").Append([]Runner{runnerOne, runnerTwo})

    // Fetch from DB
    fetchedRace := Race{}

    db.Debug().Preload("Runners", "runners.id = ?", runnerOne.ID).Find(&fetchedRace, raceOne.ID)
    if len(fetchedRace.Runners) < 1 {
        fmt.Println("error, runner not in race")
    }

    db.Delete(&raceOne)
    db.Delete(&runnerOne)
    db.Delete(&runnerTwo)
}
```

#### Using a custom SQL statement

This can be done in one SQL statement and gorm isn't very optimal with it's preloading, so if you are planning on using this often I would probably do something like this:

```golang
func isRunnerInRace(db *gorm.DB, runnerId uint, raceId uint) bool {
    count := 0
    db.Raw("SELECT COUNT(runner_id) FROM race_runners WHERE race_id = ? AND runner_id = ?", raceId,
        runnerId).Scan(&count)
    return count > 0
}
```